# Shell method for volume rotating region bounded by $x=y^2-4y$ and $x=0$ about the $x=3$

Tags: calculus

This seems like a straight-forward problem, but the numerical part got very messy which is unusual for homework problems, so just wanted to check that my concepts are correct for finding the volume when rotating a curve around $x=3$.  Typically these problems are ***no calculator*** which makes me think maybe I have a concept wrong here.

Find the Vol by rotating the region bounded by 
$x=y^2-4y$ and $x=0$ about the line $x=3$.

Graphing this I get a parabola opening to the right with vertex at $(-4,2)$.

I chose to do this problem using the **shell method** because it looks like the disk-washer method would require multiple integrals.

So, the shell method would require a $dx$ integral and so I need the integrand in terms of $x$.  Solving this equation for $y$ I get $y=2 \pm \sqrt{x+4}$.

This gives me a volume equation that looks like: V $= 2\pi \int_0^3(3-x)[(2+ \sqrt{x+4}-(2-\sqrt{x+4})]~dx$.
Simplifying this, I get $= 2\pi \int_0^3(3-x)(2\sqrt{x+4})~dx$ or

$$V= 4\pi \int_0^3(3-x)(\sqrt {x+4})~dx$$

This is a straight forward u-sub integration and I get V $=4\pi (\frac{14}{3}(x+4)^\frac32-\frac25(x+4)^\frac52)$ evaluated from $x=3, x=0)$.

Looks right but this is not a no-calc problem as I'm left with fractional exponents of $7$ as part of the answer.

Did I set this up correctly?  Using my calculator I get $V=126.139$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has the setup mostly right except the limits.  If you use the shell method to integrate over $x$, the range of $x$ that the area spans is from the vertex to the $y$-axis, i.e. $[-4, 0]$, as can be seen from your graph. Thus, the volume integral is,

$$4\pi \int_{-4}^0 (3-x)\sqrt{4+x}dx = \frac{1472\pi}{15}$$

Comment: But the problem said part of the boundry is x=0.  so, it's just the area to the right of the y axis, right?

Comment: @user163862 - it is the area bounded by $x=y^2-4y$ and $x=0$, which is the region to the left of the $y$-axis

Comment: I see that now.  Thank you.